# Extract html data using regular expressions

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

I have an html page that looks like this

```
<tr>
    <td align=left>
        <a href="history/2c0b65635b3ac68a4d53b89521216d26.html">
            <img src="/images/page.gif" border="0" title="полная информация о документе" width=20 height=20>
        </a> 
        <a href="history/2c0b65635b3ac68a4d53b89521216d26_0.html" title="C.">Th</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr align=right>
    <td align=left>
        <a href="marketing/3c0a65635b2bc68b5c43b88421306c37.html">
            <img src="/images/page.gif" border="0" title="полная информация о документе" width=20 height=20>
        </a> 
        <a href="marketing/3c0a65635b2bc68b5c43b88421306c37_0.html" title="b">aa</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to get the text

> history/2c0b65635b3ac68a4d53b89521216d26.html
>   marketing/3c0a65635b2bc68b5c43b88421306c37.html

I wrote a script in python that uses regular expressions

```
import re
a = re.compile("[0-9 a-z]{0,15}/[0-9 a-f]{32}.html")
print(a.match(s))
```

where `s`'s value is the html page above.  However when I use this script I get `"None"`.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Instead of regex try using BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Don't use regex for parsing HTML content.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Use a specialized tool - an HTML Parser.

Example (using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = u"""Your HTML here"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for link in soup.select('td a[href]'):
    print link['href']
```

Prints:

```
history/2c0b65635b3ac68a4d53b89521216d26.html
history/2c0b65635b3ac68a4d53b89521216d26_0.html
marketing/3c0a65635b2bc68b5c43b88421306c37.html
marketing/3c0a65635b2bc68b5c43b88421306c37_0.html
```

Or, if you want to get the `href` values that follow a pattern, use:

```
import re

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'\w+/\w{32}\.html')):
    print link['href']
```

where `r'\w+/\w{32}\.html'` is a regular expression that would be *applied to an `href` attribute of every `a` tag found*. It would match one or more alphanumeric characters (`\w+`), followed by a slash, followed by exactly 32 alphanumeric characters (`\w{32}`), followed by a dot (`\.`- needs to be escaped), followed by `html`.

[DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/pO3lM3/2)

Answer (score 2):

You can also write something like

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html) #html is the string containing the data to be parsed
>>> for a in soup.select('a'):
...     print a['href']
... 
history/2c0b65635b3ac68a4d53b89521216d26.html
history/2c0b65635b3ac68a4d53b89521216d26_0.html
marketing/3c0a65635b2bc68b5c43b88421306c37.html
marketing/3c0a65635b2bc68b5c43b88421306c37_0.html
```